# ReadLines to find Selector and then Get Data from the Next Line

Tags: c#, substring, readline, data-extraction, startswith

I am trying to obtain some data from a PDF but having an issue as the recurring identifier is on the line above the data I need, and for each PDF the index might be different depending on the contents
At the point of reading the file, it has been OCR'd from PDF to a Text File. So reading from the Text file.

I am trying to get the Currency; in this case to get "EUR"
Data being read:

> Currency Charge Totals
> EUR  233.00

```
var currencyLine = File.ReadLines(extractData).Last(e => e.StartsWith("Currency Charge Totals"));
out_currency = (currencyLine.Substring(currencyLine.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)).Trim();
```

The 'Currency Charge Totals' in this PDF to obtain the currency type.
I'm aware that currently this code will not return any value at the second, I've just being doing similar to obtain other data.

I just need some assistance on what I need to change to get the details from the Line below the 'ReadLine'

Comment: PDF is a binary format, not a text format.

Comment: How PDF data looks like?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: to be fair, PDF is essentially just an "enhanced" version of the Postscript printer language, which is in turn a text format, and PDF files can either be the raw text version of this or a compressed binary version. Yes, it's technically an opaque binary format, but it's not 100% out of the question to treat the file as text, for PDF examples that are in fact stored as text.

Comment: All that said, to the OP: you are barking up the wrong tree. While you can get away with reading PDF as text in some cases, it's not really standardized in a useful way. The only way to reliably extract data from PDF is to use one of the many third-party libraries that can parse the PDF for you. If you just need this for a very specific instance of a single PDF file, then you should just look at the hundreds, if not thousands, of similar questions on Stack Overflow that deal strictly with text files.

Comment: Sorry folks should have mentioned that I've already OCR'd the PDF to a Text Document. I'll update the original question to state that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need line after the one you are looking for, you can do it like this:

```
File
.ReadLines(extractData)
.SkipWhile(e => !e.StartsWith("Currency Charge Totals"))
.Skip(1)
.FirstOrDefault();
```